# ¿Por qué me da error la asignación de esta variable en C?

Tags: array, c, punteros

Estoy creando una función que me retorna una cadena de texto, y quiero asignar el valor de esa funcion a una variable, lo he intentado pero me da error, este es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *imprimir(char texto[]){
char *result = texto;
return result;
}

void main(){
char name[] = imprimir("hola mundo");
printf("%s",name);
}
```

Al copilarlo me da el siguiente error:

In function "main":
imprimir("hola mundo")
invalid initializer

Cómo podría solucionarlo, o que otro método podría utilizar para asignar el valor de la función a una variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error por el que tu código no funciona es la declaración de `name` que tiene que ser de tipo `char *` (pues ese es el tipo que retorna tu función). El tipo `char []` indica un array, en lugar de un puntero. Los arrays no los puedes inicializar con un puntero (ver la nota técnica al final para el por qué).

Al margen de eso, hay otras mejoras posibles en tu código:

- El nombre de la función. Llamarla `imprimir()` no es buena idea pues no imprime nada. Quizás debería llamarse `obtener_cadena()` o algo similar. Elegir buenos nombres para las funciones y variables es una de las tareas más importantes del programador, pues hacen que el código sea más fácil de comprender.
- La función es demasiado enrevesada ¿por qué asignas el parámetro a un puntero y luego retornas el puntero? Podrías directamente retornar lo que recibes:

  ```
  char *obtener_cadena(char texto[]) {
      return texto;
  }
  ```

  Quizás te preguntes si no hay aquí un error de tipo, pues el parámetro es `texto[]`, pero lo que deberíamos retornar es `char *`. Lo cierto es que no hay error, pues la sintaxis `char variable[]` **cuando se usa como parámetro** es equivalente a `char *variable`. Es decir, realmente `texto` es un puntero, por lo que es válido retornarlo.
- Pero a la vista de la función que acabo de escribir resulta bastante obvio que esa función es totalmente superflua. ¿Para qué escribir una función que simplemente retorna lo que ha recibido? Para eso podemos asignar directamente el texto en el programa principal.
- Un detalle menor, `main()` debe declararse como retornando `int` para evitar *warnings* en la compilación. Y debe terminar por tanto con un `return` de un entero.

Propongo por tanto este otro programa:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *name = "hola mundo";
    printf("%s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

**Nota y explicación técnica**.

En esta versión del programa en la que he eliminado la función auxiliar, se podría ya usar `char name[]` si lo prefieres. El resultado es ligeramente diferente en cuanto al uso de la memoria, pero equivalente en su funcionalidad.

Al usar `char name[]` el compilador reserva un trozo de memoria en la pila del tamaño necesario para que entre la cadena "hola mundo" más su terminador (11 bytes) y le pone a ese trozo el nombre `name`. Esta solución requiere por tanto 11 bytes en la pila (posiblemente sean redondeados a 16, por motivos de eficiencia en el acceso, pero eso ya depende del compilador)

Al usar `char *name` el compilador reserva un trozo de memoria en la pila del tamaño necesario para un puntero (ese tamaño es constante independientemente de a dónde se le vaya a hacer apuntar, y es de 8 bytes en arquitecturas de 64 bits). Cuando el programa se ejecute ese puntero será asignado para que apunte a otro lugar de la memoria (fuera ya de la pila) en donde estará la cadena "hola mundo". Esta solución requiere por tanto 8 bytes en la pila y otros 11 fuera de ella, en la zona de memoria de las cadenas literales.

En tu versión inicial la primera sintaxis no se podía usar porque el compilador no podría saber que la cadena que vas a asignar tiene 11 bytes, pues la cadena sólo se sabrá cuando se ejecute la función `imprimir()` pero no en tiempo de compilación, de ahí el error.